# JNI: освобождение памяти jstring. NewStringUTF

Tags: java, c++, c, jni, native

Функция dll (C++) возвращает `jstring`, созданный с помощью `NewStringUTF`:

```
...
sprintf(result, "Any data. Not a const string");
jstring jres = env -> NewStringUTF(result);
free(result);
return jres;
```

Массив символов `result`, очевидно, нужно очистить.
Но нужно ли освобождать память jres? Или JVM об этом позаботится?

Comment: *"Массив символов result, очевидно, нужно очистить."* - *"Это «очевидно», сказал себе Ханстен, великолепный пример логики «блюдцепоклонников», лихой скачок через барьер несуразицы, совершенно ошеломляющий нормальный разум."* ¿В примере `result` даже не объявлено, с чего бы должно быть очевидно, что нужно что-то очищать? А с jres должен разбираться вызывающий код.

Comment: Объявление и выделение памяти `result` опущено, т.к. к вопросу отношения не имеет.
Вопрос про `jres`, нужно ли как-то явным образом очищать память или JNI сделает это под капотом ?
Нахожу противоречивую информацию.

Comment: Как то, нужно ли очищать тут `result` или не нужно, зависит от того, как оно объявлено и инициализировано, так и то, что нужно делать с `jres`, зависит от того, что будет с ним дальше.

Comment: Результат вызова нативной функции `dll` из `java` посредством `jni`, будет, предположим, напечатан.

Comment: Все ресурсы выделяемые в библиотеке, должны быть освобождены вызывающим кодом, а не вызывающей стороной